# CSS: Why container overflows when child is floated

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Why parent div element stop adjusting height when it's child is floated? I have the following snippet of HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="overflown_container">
      <button class="button">Button</button>
      <button class="button" style="height:80px; float: right">Overflown button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS

```
#container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 60vw;
  margin: auto;
}

#overflown_container {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button {
  float: bottom;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

Now the result is following:

[image]

If I add `overflow: auto` attribute to overflown_container, it will adjust it's height, but then I should have to add overflow attribute to all containing elements until the root which is not desired. Also, I would like to align both buttons to bottom, but it seems impossible to float Button1 to the overflown area.

Why floating button to right causes the overflow? How to avoid it, and achieve design, where both buttons are at the opposite ends of container, may or may not have fixed dimension, are aligned at the common baseline (bottom) and containers grows their dimensions without overflow?

Comment: i have eddited my answer.. please check.. i think you need this..

Answer (score 0):

floating element won't be properly contained by its container by default.

to make the container adjusts to floating element's width and height, you need to add clearfix property to it

following http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

add this to your css

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

and add the clearfix class to the wrapper of floating element

another thing is that, there is no float:bottom in css, only float left or right. to make it 'float' bottom, either add enough margin-top to the floatng element, or don't use float, use position: absolute instead

```
    .parent{
        position: relative;
    }
    .child {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with floating elements is that they take the element outside of the normal flow of the document. Clearfix is a useful solution for this and I have implemented it here but it does not achieve what you seem to be looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/07sjLaLa/

As you can see in the following example, dropping the `float: right` from the button aligns the buttons on the bottom as requested: https://jsfiddle.net/07sjLaLa/1/

However, now you've got the issue of a button not being aligned as you wished it to be. The easiest way to accomplish a right alignment without a float is to apply a right alignment to the parent element but obviously you can't do that with mixed-alignment objects, so we just need to add a new set of parent elements: https://jsfiddle.net/07sjLaLa/2/

Please note that in all of these examples the wrapper element `#container` does not expand but this can be resolved by including clearfix on this element as well. https://jsfiddle.net/07sjLaLa/3/

Comment: I am curious, why those span wrappers are required to float first button to bottom?

Comment: They aren't required to float the first button to the bottom, they are required for aligning the second button to the right side.